# Dense and continuous embedding

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

1. What is the mean of "dense and continuous embedding" between to
   space X and Y?
2. Are there such these relations between $L_2(U)$, $H^1(U)$ and dual of $H^1(U)$ for some open subsets $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: For vector spaces $X,Y$ an embedding of $X$ into $Y$ is an injective map $i:X\to Y$. If this map is continuous and the image $i(X)$ is a dense subspace of $Y$ then this is a dense, continuous embedding. I am unsure what definitions you are using of $H^1(U)$, but if it is the Hilbert space $W^{1,2}$ then this is seperable and thus unitarily equivalent to any other seperable Hilbert space, including $L^2$.

Comment: Thanks, your answer help me more than more. :)